# python comparing two matrices

Tags: python

In the below shown matrices i want to match the first element in both the matrices. If the first element is equal then i need match the second element from both the matrices and so on.. 
if the elements are same then print "same" else print "not same"....

My question is how this in the optimal way also for m*n where m=n always

```
 for i in a1:
     for j in a2:
        if i!=j:
           break
         else:
           //compare the next corresponding columns and print "same" or "not same"


 a1=[1,44,55],[2,33,66],[3,77,91]  

 a2=[1,44,55],[2,45,66],[3,77,91]    

 OR 

 a1=[1,44,55]
    [2,33,66]
    [3,77,91]  

 a2=[1,44,55]
    [2,45,66]
    [3,77,91]
```

Comment: The syntax for `a1`, `a2` doesn't look correct

Comment: I wanted to draw that in a matrix form so i had shown as indicated

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's wrong with `a1 == a2`?

```
In [1]: a1=[[1,44,55],
   ...:     [2,33,66],
   ...:     [3,77,91]]

In [2]: a2=[[1,44,55],
   ...:     [2,45,66], # <- second element differs
   ...:     [3,77,91]]

In [3]: a1 == a2
Out[3]: False

In [4]: a1=[[1,44,55],
   ...:     [2,33,66],
   ...:     [3,77,91]]

In [5]: a2=[[1,44,55],
   ...:     [2,33,66],
   ...:     [3,77,91]]

In [6]: a1 == a2
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: So `a == b` compares list recursively?

Comment: I get a ValueError when I do this

Answer (score 15):

You may run into some issues due to floating point rounding errors.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array(1.1)
>>> print x * x
1.21
>>> x * x == 1.21
False
>>> x * x
1.2100000000000002
>>> np.allclose(x * x, 1.21)
True
```

To compare whether two numerical matrices are equal, it is recommended that you use `np.allclose()`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([[1.1, 1.3], [1.3, 1.1]])
>>> y = np.array([[1.21, 1.69], [1.69, 1.21]])
>>> x * x
array([[ 1.21,  1.69],
       [ 1.69,  1.21]])
>>> x * x == y
array([[False, False],
       [False, False]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.allclose(x * x, y)
True
```

Answer (score 5):

In case you are using numpy arrays, use the `.all()` and `.any()`.

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
y = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
(x == y).all()
>> True

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
y = np.array([[11, 21, 31], [41, 4, 61]])
(x == y).any()
>> True # since x[1][0] == y[1][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna do operations over matrix, `numpy` is the best library you could use

```
In [11]: a = numpy.matrix([[1,44,55],
    ...:                   [2,33,66],
    ...:                   [3,77,91]])

In [12]: b = numpy.matrix([[1,44,55],
    ...:                   [2,45,66],
    ...:                   [3,77,91]])

In [13]: a == b
Out[13]: 
matrix([[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False,  True],
        [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is solution with lists without using numpy.

```
def isIdentical(a: list, b: list) -> bool:
    rows, cols = len(a), len(a[0])
    return all([a[i][j] == b[i][j] for j in range(cols) for i in range(rows)])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from scipy import sparse
I = np.arange(0, 3).repeat(3)     
J =np.arange(9) 
V = np.arange(9) 
W = sparse.coo_matrix((V, (I, J)), shape=(9,9))
print(np.array_equiv(W.todense(),W.todense().T)) #False Shape consistent (broadcastable)
print(np.array_equal(W.todense(),W.todense().T)) #False (exact shape)
print(W.todense().all()==W.todense().T.all()) #True
print(W.todense==W.todense().T)
print(W.todense()[:,1], W.todense()[1,:])
```

Why using print(W.todense().all()==W.todense().T.all()) #True returns True, while W is not symmetric?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).